# viewwillappear and viewdidappear not called in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode9

I have an iPad app where I add a Landingviewcontroller to a navigationcontroller and add this navigationcontroller to window's rootviewcontroller. I used to perform few actions in LandingviewController's viewwillappear. But, suddenly in Xcode9 it stopped calling. Here is my code -

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication *) application {

     self.landingPageController = [[LandingPageViewController alloc] init];
     self.introViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.landingPageController];

    _window.rootViewController = self.introViewController;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**ViewDidAppear** and **ViewWillAppear** methods are not called in **LandingPageViewController**.

Any idea why are these methods are not getting called?

**EDIT: Added viewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear methods**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

   [self setupCoverView];

 }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // load news view controller
    [self news:userChanged]; 
 }
```

Comment: Show your `viewWillAppear` & `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: is the view being shown to you ??

Comment: Shouldn't introViewController be the window's root VC? You wrote that the NAVIGATION controller is the window's root, but in the code it looks the other way around.

Comment: @UmarFarooque - Yes, jus loading the XIB contents.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Using xib

Comment: @ArikSegal - I changed it to landingpage just to see if its calling.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  _window.rootViewController = self.landingPageController;
```

with

```
  _window.rootViewController = self.introViewController;
```

`Navigation controller` should be your `rootviewcontroller` in your case!

Comment: if it is not allocate the `UINavigationController` also it will work with out  `Navigation controller`

Comment: yeah thats right but as he is taking navigation contoller with viewcontroller as root so he should set nav as window's root! @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

[Targets Deployment config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCiSw.png)

check your targets config，delete value of Main Interface，then add code at begin of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions。
`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]`